# C# vs2019 library could not be loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't know what's going on, but when I try to create a new subpage in asp net mvc vs2019 I get an error:

There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Failed to render template because of the following errors:
There was a problem loading the assembly 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\3.5.0.0_(publicKey)\System.Data.Linq.dll' The following Exception was thrown: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not loaded file or assembly 'File:///C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\3.5.0.0_(publicKey)\System.Data.Linq.dll' or on of its dependencies.

I will only add that before everything was ok. I spent many days on the network to solve it but I did not succeed, maybe someone will know what's going on.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework is the project targetting? Given the version of System.Data.Linq I'm hoping you're not going to say .NET Framework 3.5!

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using too?

Comment: PS. Version information: Microsoft .NET Framework version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET version:4.8.4494.0. Server error in application '/'.
The file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. The specified file could not be found.

Comment: That seems to be a different version of System.Data.Linq than in your question! It sounds as though you don't have [.NET Framework 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17718) installed.

Comment: I tried to install versions 4.0, but the message says that since I have 4.8, I can't have 4.0 because 4.8 includes everything that is in 4.0.
Will reinstall everything next week, maybe that will help.
Phuzi thanks for your help and replies!